# Payara singleton per cluster implementation

Tags: jakarta-ee, payara

Does EJB have clustering defined I have found clustering the Stateless or Statefull beans are platform specific for ex. Jboss has @Clustered annotation but in Payara ? I have the same application on multiple machines and I would like to perform a leader election or a kind of singletion call per whole cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest release (from 182) of Payara Server and Payara Micro has the ability to use clustered singletons, as described in this blog post: https://blog.payara.fish/introduction-to-clustered-singleton

You just need to use `fish.payara.cluster.Clustered` (and make sure the bean is serializable) as the blog explains:

```java
import fish.payara.cluster.Clustered;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@Clustered @Singleton
public class MyClusteredSingletonEJB implements Serializable { /* ... */ }

@Clustered @ApplicationScoped
public class MyClusteredSingletonCDI implements Serializable { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: How can I connect them in same cluster ? Do I need install Hazelcast for discovery ?

Comment: Hazelcast is already present in Payara. I would recommend you read the docs around the domain data grid, particularly the discovery modes (there's too much to cover in a short comment): https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/payara-server/hazelcast/discovery.html